# How to select users with a gold Angular badge

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer

I'm using the following query on SEDE to select top 100 users with `angular` gold badge:

```
SELECT TOP 100 UserId AS [User Link], COUNT(*) 
FROM Badges
WHERE Name IN ('angular')
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

However, it's giving me users without `angular` gold badges. I think that I should somehow specify the type of the badge, but I don't see where. There's a badge class field in the table but I can't seem to find a table which provides a description for this.

Comment: I don't think you even need a special class for gold badges. You can get language badges only one time so a person with "count = 3" obviously has bronze, silver and gold, whereas someone with "count = 2" only has bronze and silver. You get what I mean?

Comment: yeah, do you mean that a language badge of a particular type can occur only once?

Comment: Yes. You can't have two gold angular badges. So you should only have 3 entries in that table with badge "angular" if have gold. Btw the Class for the Gold Badge is probably "1" (Since the count increases for 2 and 3: `SELECT Count(*) FROM Badges WHERE Name IN ('angular') and Class = '1'`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there, you're indeed missing the `Class` field:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 UserId AS [User Link], COUNT(*) 
FROM Badges
WHERE Name IN ('angular') AND Class = 1
GROUP BY UserId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The [database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/295232) contains a description of this field:

> #### Badges
>
> ...
>
> - Class
>
>   1. Gold
>   2. Silver
>   3. Bronze

The [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/693013/gold-angular-badge-holders) currently returns just 8 users.